# Peak Detection Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get all large peaks values of this signal :

[image]

As you can see there is one large peak followed by one smaller peak, and I want to get each value of the largest peak. I already tried this `[pks1,locs1] = findpeaks(y1,'MinPeakHeight',??);` but I can't find what I can write instead of the ?? knowing that the signal will not be the same every time (of course there will ever be a large+smaller peak schema but time intervals and amplitudes can change). I tried a lot of things using std(), mean(),max() but none of the combination works properly.

Any ideas on how can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `'MinPeakDistance'` keyword and enter a minimum distance between the two peaks slightly higher than the distance between the large peak and the following small peak. So for example:

```
[pks1,locs1] = findpeaks(y1,'MinPeakDistance',0.3);
```

**Edit**:
If the time between peaks (and the following smaller one) varies a lot you'll probably have to do some post-processing. First find all the peaks including the smaller second ones. Then in your array of peaks remove every peak which is significantly lower than its two neighbours.

You could also try fiddling with `'MinPeakProminence'`.

Generally these problems require a lot of calibration for the final few percent of the algorithms accuracy, and there's no universal cure.

I also recommend having a look at all the other options in the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).